# Alternating sort column

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-orm

Came around a weird requirement...

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Assume we have:

```
by_time = MyModel.objects.order_by('time')
by_prio = MyModel.objects.order_by('priority')
```

I need to present the items with an alternating sort order. E.g. 1 item sorted by time, 1 sorted by priority, the next by time, and so on... Each item needs to be unique in the list (can't just join the two lists into a twice longer one).

How can I implement such a thing and keep it relatively efficient?

*Edit:*
A few notes:

1. The items in the ending list must be *unique*, thus I can't just merge the two lists.
2. If I merge the lists and remove the duplicates afterwards, the sort order will be ruined (e.g. 2 adjacent values by the same order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two lists this way:

```
>>> result = [None]*(len(by_time)+len(by_prio))
>>> result[::2] = by_time
>>> result[1::2] = by_prio
>>> result = [result.pop(i) for i in range(len(result))[::-1] if result.count(result[i]) > 1 ]
```

Comment: a. duplicates.  
b. if I just remove the duplicates it ruins the sort order.  
c. really nice way of alternate-merging two lists. upvoted.